# Using VBA in Excel, How do I clear everything past a specific column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this for clearing everything past a specific row but I would like it to work with columns instead of rows. X in this case should be 6

```
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
      .Rows( X & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
  End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 With Sheets("Sheet1")
      .Range(.Cells(1,X).Address & ":" & .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).Address).Columns.ClearContents
 End With
```

where X is the column number or letter you wish to start with.